# Unable to pass NameValueCollection to POST WebAPI 5.0 core in ASP.NET / C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to pass `NameValueCollection` to ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API controller (`WebserviceController.cs`) using `HttpPost`. I am trying to post 2 name values pairs as a sample: `key1,value1` and `key2,value2`

C# (.NET Framework 4.8) Client code is:

```
webClient WebClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
String response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(webClient.UploadValues("https://localhost:44312/webservice", new NameValueCollection() { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } }));
```

Postman screenshot:

[image: Post Call]

And I get error in C# client: `The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.`

And in Postman:

[image: Error]

I tried the following 2 approaches to receive `NameValueCollection` to ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API controller using `HttpPost`:

```
namespace Webservice.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WebserviceController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public String Post([FromBody] NameValueCollection Values)
        {
            return "values received";
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class classNameValueCollection
{
    public NameValueCollection SampleValues;
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WebserviceController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public String Post([FromBody] classNameValueCollection Values)
    {
        return "values received";
    }
}
```

In the first one I am directly trying to get `NameValueCollection` in the `Post` method, and in the second approach I created a class that has a `NameValueCollection` variable and used the class object to receive `NameValueCollection` in `Post` method.

But I get the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with postman.

```
namespace Webservice.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WebserviceController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public String Post([FromForm] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection Values)
        {
            string val1 = Values["key1"].ToString();
            string val2 = Values["key2"].ToString();
            return "values received";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `NameValueCollection` and `FromBody`, use `IFormCollection` and `FromForm`

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u1lP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong type in parameters, right way is

```
public String Post([FromForm] classNameValueCollection Values)
```